# How to make MFMailComposeViewController not show the status bar?

Tags: ios, statusbar

I have an iOS app that normally does not show the status bar by using prefersStatusBarHidden returning YES in the root view controller class. I use MFMailComposeViewController to compose a mail message using presentViewController:animated:completion. I cannot make MFMailComposeViewController not show the status bar. I tried subclassing MFMailComposeViewController and make prefersStatusBarHidden return YES but that did not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Try creating a new row in your app plist file ("View controller-based status bar appearance"/"UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance") and set it to NO.

This should override your "prefersStatusBarHidden" method as well- however, since you are trying to hide it anyways, should not be an issue for you.

Comment: I tried a lot of different approaches, this one did the trick!